# Access local ftp

Tags: command-line, ftp, gvfs

I was using ubuntu 10.10.

I had a strange situation where I was setting up a small network all with fixed IPs.  I had a NAS drive that I had enabled ftp on.

when I used the `connect to server` menu I was able to connect fine (or just entering in the URL in nautilus).

However from the command line the `ftp` command didn't work, and gave an unknown host error.  I was able to ping the drive however.

In the end I used the `gvfs-host` command to enable a scripted connection.  I'm just wondering if anyone has come across this problem

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: A little concern have you added the the `hostname` and `IP` in the **/etc/hosts** file ?

You can also try **telnet x.x.x.x 21** (x.x.x.x = IP of the FTP server) to check that the server is listening on the default FTP port.

Comment: I was trying to connect just using the IP address so I don't think `/etc/hosts` should come into play (is that correct?). I would imagine since `gvfs-mount` was able to connect without any different port parameter that it's just on the usual port 21.

Comment: do you have to provide a username/password in nautilus ? (using ftp with login) or a public ftp

Comment: 2012 long time, I'm not sure if it is the case. Try FTP passive mode `ftp -p ...`. Or may be verbose/debug `ftp -d -v ...`

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the configuration file is following these attributes (run `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf` to edit it):

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

**Save and Exit that file**

Please make sure the following directory is created and that the permissions are applied to it (replacing user name with the user name of the linux user that will access the system)

```
mkdir /home/username/files
chown root:root /home/username
sudo service vsftpd restart
```